# R bigmemory: how to access matrix/keep in shared memory after script got executed

Tags: r, shared-memory, r-bigmemory

I use the `bigmemory` package to put a very large matrix into shared memory (see script below, so it can be accessed in parallel by scripts in other R sessions.

I now want to execute the script in a non-interactive way. The problem is, that if I run it with `Rscript`, the matrix is removed from shared memory right after the `Rscript` process ended. I could add `Sys.sleep(99999)` to the end of the script, but I am wondering if there is any better way to acclompish this. Any ideas?

```
library(bigmemory)

m = read.big.matrix("matrix.txt", type='double', shared = TRUE, header = FALSE, sep = "\t")

sign = describe(m)
dput(sign, "matrix.signature")
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly by "keeping in shared memory after script got executed". As well as "keep the session alive after the script got executed".

Comment: @F.Privé : can you understand it better now?

Comment: When you say that you want to keep the shared memory, is it because you want to run many scripts using this data without having to map the data on disk each time?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with "map the data on disk each time", but yes, I want to access the data in shared memory with scripts that I run in separate R sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the descriptor `sign` on disk, then you can just use `attach.big.matrix()` in another session:

```
m <- attach.big.matrix("matrix.signature")
```

Comment: The problem is that if the other session stops i cannot access the matrix anymore via attach.big.matrix because it is removed. How can I keep the other session alive after the matrix is put into shared memory?

Comment: Yes, you can. `"matrix.signature"` is the path to the file on disk that contains the necessary information (descriptor) to rebuild the `big.matrix` object.

Comment: If the object in shared memory is not there anymore, the descriptor is useless. The descriptor is basically only a pointer to the object. I am asking for help how to keep this object (i.e. the matrix) in shared memory. At the moment the only solutions I see is to run the read.big.matrix script from above in an interactive session (and don't close the session) or if I add sth like Sys.sleep(9999999) when running it with Rscript.

Comment: I see. Why not using a filebacked big.matrix?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. You? How is the performance vs shared memory?

Comment: Found out that the matrix stays in shared memory as long as it is attached with attach.big.matrix in at least one session. I think I know now how to handle it

Answer (score 0):

As long as the matrix is attached in at least one R session it remains in an isolated part of the RAM. The best practice to prevent the matrix from being lost is to fileback it. There is no performance penalty involved, but you have to be aware that in the designated location on your hard drive, these data reside and remain there until you delete them explicitly. Even closing all R sessions won't delete them. The finalizer is deactivated in this case.